# Check mysql_query results if DELETE query worked?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have a DELETE query which deletes a record from a mysql db.

is there any way to make sure if the delete was performed or not?

I mean, for a query to FIND stuff you do

```
     $res=mysql_query($var);
     $nr=mysql_num_rows($res);
```

and you get nr of rows returned.

Is there any similiar method for deletion of records?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows). It does not require the response as a parameter.

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM whatever');
$num = mysql_affected_rows();
```

Also, I like [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) better than the classic `mysql_` functions. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_affected_rows()` extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead,the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$mysqli->query("DO SOMETHING");
$mysqli->affected_rows;
```